# Moving code to class causes HttpException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have written code that exports data from a webpage to excel using EPPlus that I want to reuse multiple times across my project so I have moved the code to its own class.

It works fine when in the code on the page but when I move it to its own class I get the following error on the `Response.Clear()` line:

`System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Response is not available in this context`

Here is my code

**ExcelHelper Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;

namespace myClassLib
{
    public class ExcelHelper : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public void exportExcel(DataTable myDataTable)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Output.xlsx");

            DataTable dt= myDataTable;

            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
            using(pck)
            {
                ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);

                int colNumber = 1;

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) 
                {

                    if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        wsDt.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
                    }
                    colNumber = colNumber + 1;
                }

                wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

                Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            }

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }

    }
}
```

**Code to call class**

```
ExcelHelper myExcelHelper = new ExcelHelper();
myExcelHelper.exportExcel(myDataTable);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to get rid of all System.Web related code from your class if you really want to use it everywhere and pass needed property values as options to the method

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? Is this code in a separate project or in the web project? Basically you can't access the Response object from this, so we need to determine the other questions first.

Comment: Apologies. using webforms, code is in a separate project but I have added references correctly as other classes run fine.

Comment: How are you calling `ExcelHelper`? If you're doing `var helper = new ExcelHelper();` then you're not going to be able to access that context. See how the `new` keyword works. You could pass the current context to your helper when you instantiate it and then access it that way. Basically your problem right now is that `Response` is null.

Comment: The code that I use to call the class is at the end of my question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that, but you're doing what I assumed and my response is why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You inherited your helper from [`Page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx), probably because you wanted access to the [`HttpResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) instance offered in `Response` property. The `Page` class should however be instantiated by the ASP.NET http pipeline so it gets all its inner state correctly setup. That doesn't happen in your scenario. If you refactor it as follows you can have your Excel generation in a helper class with some extra goodies to export to file as well.

```
public class ExcelExporter 
{
    DataTable dt;
    string filename = "Output.xlsx";
    // create exporter for datatable
    public ExcelExporter(DataTable dt)
    {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    // creates an exporter for a datatable and filename
    public ExcelExporter(DataTable dt, string filename):this(dt)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    // exports excel to given httpResponse
    public void Export(HttpResponse response)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", 
            String.Format("attachment;filename={0}",filename));

        Response.BinaryWrite(Export());

        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }

    // export excel package in path with defaukt name
    public void Export(string path)
    {
        Export(path, filename);
    }

    // export excel package as file in path
    public void Export(string path, string file)
    {
        var full = Path.Combine(path, file);
        File.WriteAllBytes(full, Export());
    }

    //exort Excel package as Byte array
    public byte[] Export()
    {
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        using (pck)
        {
            ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);

            int colNumber = 1;

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {

                if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                {
                    wsDt.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";
                }
                colNumber = colNumber + 1;
            }

            wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
            return pck.GetAsByteArray();   
        }
    }

}
```

To use this new version you'll call it as follows from your ASP.NET page:

```
myExcelHelper = new ExcelExproter(myDataTable);
myExcelHelper.Export(Response); // Response will be the HttpResponse of the current executing page
```